# Endnotes in MS Word on specific page, modify heading styles to not create new section

Tags: ms-word, sections, footnotes

I am writing an instruction manual with many endnotes and footnotes. I want the endnotes to be on a specific page, specifically after the references, say they are on page x.

The document is split into many sections using the different styles available in word.

- If I choose the endnotes should be at the end of the document, then I cannot put any text after them, which I would like to do.
- If I choose the endnotes should be at the end of the section, then each new heading style starts a new section, so the endnotes are smack in the middle of the page.

**Is there a way to create an endnote and make it appear immediately after a specific section, say my References?**

*If a potential solution involves macros, I have no experience writing them, so I'll need to know how to create and insert them if that is the case.*

Thanks.

P.S. There is no endnotes tag so I used `footnotes`.

Comment: Endnotes must appear at the end of document or section. This is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon, thank you. I will move the question over later today.